# I have saved a drawing in a bitmap in my Database, how can I redraw it?

Tags: android, sqlite, canvas, bitmap, draw

In my activity I can make a Signature drawing and I save it in my SQLite database with the "saveToDatabase" button. When I re-open the activity I want to load the drawing from my database, but I can't figure out how to! Can anyone help? I already decoded the bitmap at "Adding Signature from database", but what do I need to do next?

Here is my code:

```
public class WerkbonDetailsActivity extends Activity{

public Werkbon chosenWorkorder;
Button mClear, mGetSign, saveToDatabase;
LinearLayout mContent;
signature mSignature;
public static String tempDir;
public int count = 1;
public String current = null;
private Bitmap mBitmap;
View mView;
Database db = new Database(this);
int chosenWorkorderposition = 0;
Paint paintPieFill;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_werkbondetails);



    tempDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + getResources().getString(R.string.external_dir) + "/";
    prepareDirectory();
    current = count + ".png";
    mContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    mSignature = new signature(this, null);
    mSignature.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    mContent.addView(mSignature, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    mClear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_handtekeningwissen);
    mGetSign = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getsign);
    saveToDatabase = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
    mView = mContent;

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras != null) {
        chosenWorkorderposition = (int)extras.getInt("chosenWorkorderposition");
    }   
    chosenWorkorder = db.getWerkbon(chosenWorkorderposition + 1);


    mClear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {         
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Log.v("log_tag", "Panel Cleared");
            mSignature.clear();
        }
    });

    mGetSign.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {         
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Log.v("log_tag", "Panel Saved");
            mView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            mSignature.save(mView);
        }
    });

    saveToDatabase.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {         
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
        mBitmap =  Bitmap.createBitmap (mContent.getWidth(), mContent.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);;
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        v.draw(canvas);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream); 
        byte[] bitmapdata = stream.toByteArray();
        chosenWorkorder.setHandtekening(bitmapdata);

        db.updateWerkbon(chosenWorkorder);
        }
    });

    //Adding Signature from database
    if(chosenWorkorder.getHandtekening() != null){
        ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(chosenWorkorder.getHandtekening());
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

private boolean prepareDirectory() 
{
    try 
    {
        if (makedirs()) 
        {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Could not initiate File System.. Is Sdcard mounted properly?", 1000).show();
        return false;
    }
}

private boolean makedirs() 
{
    File tempdir = new File(tempDir);
    if (!tempdir.exists())
        tempdir.mkdirs();

    if (tempdir.isDirectory()) 
    {
        File[] files = tempdir.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) 
        {
            if (!file.delete()) 
            {
                System.out.println("Failed to delete " + file);
            }
        }
    }
    return (tempdir.isDirectory());
}


public class signature extends View 
{
    private static final float STROKE_WIDTH = 5f;
    private static final float HALF_STROKE_WIDTH = STROKE_WIDTH / 2;
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private Path path = new Path();

    private float lastTouchX;
    private float lastTouchY;
    private final RectF dirtyRect = new RectF();

    public signature(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
    {
         super(context, attrs);
         paint.setAntiAlias(true);
         paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
         paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
         paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
         paint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
    }

    public void save(View v) 
    {
        Log.v("log_tag", "Width: " + v.getWidth());
        Log.v("log_tag", "Height: " + v.getHeight());
        if(mBitmap == null)
        {
            mBitmap =  Bitmap.createBitmap (mContent.getWidth(), mContent.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);;
        }
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        String FtoSave = tempDir + current;
        File file = new File(FtoSave);
        try 
        {
            FileOutputStream mFileOutStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            v.draw(canvas); 
            mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, mFileOutStream); 
            mFileOutStream.flush();
            mFileOutStream.close();
            String url = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), mBitmap, "title", null);
            Log.v("log_tag","url" + url);
        }
        catch(Exception e) 
        { 
            Log.v("log_tag", e.toString()); 
        } 
    }

    public void clear() 
    {
         path.reset();
         invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {
         canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
    {
         float eventX = event.getX();
         float eventY = event.getY();

         switch (event.getAction()) 
         {
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                 path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
                 lastTouchX = eventX;
                 lastTouchY = eventY;
                 return true;

           case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

           case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                 resetDirtyRect(eventX, eventY);
                 int historySize = event.getHistorySize();
                 for (int i = 0; i < historySize; i++) 
                 {
                       float historicalX = event.getHistoricalX(i);
                       float historicalY = event.getHistoricalY(i);
                       expandDirtyRect(historicalX, historicalY);
                       path.lineTo(historicalX, historicalY);
                 }
                 path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
                 break;

           default:
                 debug("Ignored touch event: " + event.toString());
                 return false;
         }

         invalidate((int) (dirtyRect.left - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
             (int) (dirtyRect.top - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
             (int) (dirtyRect.right + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
             (int) (dirtyRect.bottom + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH));

         lastTouchX = eventX;
         lastTouchY = eventY;

         return true;
    }

    private void debug(String string) 
    {
    }

    private void expandDirtyRect(float historicalX, float historicalY) 
    {
         if (historicalX < dirtyRect.left) 
         {
           dirtyRect.left = historicalX;
         } 
         else if (historicalX > dirtyRect.right) 
         {
           dirtyRect.right = historicalX;
         }

         if (historicalY < dirtyRect.top) 
         {
           dirtyRect.top = historicalY;
         } 
         else if (historicalY > dirtyRect.bottom) 
         {
           dirtyRect.bottom = historicalY;
         }
    }

    private void resetDirtyRect(float eventX, float eventY) 
    {
         dirtyRect.left = Math.min(lastTouchX, eventX);
         dirtyRect.right = Math.max(lastTouchX, eventX);
         dirtyRect.top = Math.min(lastTouchY, eventY);
         dirtyRect.bottom = Math.max(lastTouchY, eventY);
    }
}//signature
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the byte array from your database and you can decode it with this method:

```
  private static Bitmap deserialize(byte[] data) throws IOException,
        ClassNotFoundException {
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(in);
    return (Bitmap) is.readObject();
}
```

Comment: I can't get it to work this way! Where do i need to put this?